My Workbook.SheetChange event is not working properly
I have the following code:
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("A1").Calculate
End Sub

Tub does not work until I do a calculation on another sheet. Just switching the sheets does not trigger the sub. What could be possible issues?
The automatic calculation is turned off, if that is relevant.

Btw, you should specify the parent worksheet for Range("A1"). "Just switching the sheets" doesn't trigger this event; that sounds like the Workbook_SheetActivate event.

Please share in detail what you are trying to do and in which case (when) so we can offer some help. The Workbook SheetChange event is triggered when you manually enter values in cells of any worksheet e.g. you write a value to A1, you copy A1:A10 as values to B1:B10, or you use VBA to write a value to a cell e.g. Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1,... etc. Sh is a reference to the sheet where the cells were changed while Target is a reference to the changed cells. All this means that your code should contain the Sh and (or at least) the Target variable which it doesn't.

Workbook_SheetChange is triggered when one or multiple cells on a sheet are changed (by entering or pasting data or by VBA code).
It is not triggered when the value of a formula changes: For that you need to handle the Workbook_SheetCalculate event.
It is also not triggered when you select another sheet. For that you need to handle the Workbook_SheetActivate event.
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Debug.Print "Activate: " & Sh.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "Change: " & Sh.Name & "!" & Target.Cells(1).Address & " changed to " & Target.Cells(1).Value
End Sub

